# How to hide "Log Off" button Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows

I have created a Standard user and disabled the "Switch User/Lock" from registry with the followings :

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer [StartMenuLogOff=1]
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System [HideFastUserSwitching=1]
3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System [DisableLockWorkstation=1]

These are working fine.

but still "log off" button enabled.

I tried this one 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced [StartMenuLogoff=1]

but no luck.

Please let me know how can I disable it.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via Group Policy (local or global):

Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar \ Remove Logoff on the Start Menu

Comment: Tried the same but no luck.

Comment: Are you doing it from a local GPO? Or Global? Have you done a gpresult to see if the policy is being applied?

Comment: I have Cloud VM hosted on Amazon Ec2, accessing it using RDP and don't wan't to standrad user logoff them. 

I am trying using "Administrator' account.

Comment: GPO: Local Group Policy
                KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoLogoff
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\StartMenuLogOff
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled